# Replace ArrayBuffer variable in JS chrome console

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I am trying to replace the below ArrayBuffer `a`, from chrome console.

But when I do a = [43,43,....], it makes it an array. How can I initialise a new Arraybuffer ?

```
a: ArrayBuffer(86)
[[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(86) [-8, 6, 9, 91, 75, 107, -4, 2, 49, 51, -8, 1, -8, 2, 52, -4, 69, 10, 53, 10, 27, 57, 49, 56, 50, 56, 53, 54, 49, 48, 56, 56, 55, 64, 115, 46, 119, 104, 97, 116, 115, 97, 112, 112, 46, 110, 101, 116, 16, 1, 26, 20, 51, 69, 66, 48, 57, 69, 50, 48, 49, 51, 69, 65, 65, 67, 50, 56, 66, 51, 55, 54, 18, 4, 10, 2, 108, 111, 24, -32, -71, -91, -35, 5, 32, 1]

[[Int16Array]]: Int16Array(43) [1784, 23305, 27467, 764, 13105, 504, 760, -972, 2629, 2613, 14619, 14385, 14386, 13877, 12337, 14392, 16439, 11891, 26743, 29793, 24947, 28784, 28206, 29797, 272, 5146, 17715, 12354, 17721, 12338, 13105, 16709, 17217, 14386, 13122, 13879, 1042, 522, 28524, -8168, -23111, 1501, 288]

[[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(86) [248, 6, 9, 91, 75, 107, 252, 2, 49, 51, 248, 1, 248, 2, 52, 252, 69, 10, 53, 10, 27, 57, 49, 56, 50, 56, 53, 54, 49, 48, 56, 56, 55, 64, 115, 46, 119, 104, 97, 116, 115, 97, 112, 112, 46, 110, 101, 116, 16, 1, 26, 20, 51, 69, 66, 48, 57, 69, 50, 48, 49, 51, 69, 65, 65, 67, 50, 56, 66, 51, 55, 54, 18, 4, 10, 2, 108, 111, 24, 224, 185, 165, 221, 5, 32, 1]
byteLength: (...)
__proto__: ArrayBuffer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just a new ArrayBuffer it would just be

```
 a = new ArrayBuffer(length)
```

If you are needing a new buffer with given values you have to use a a typed array or view in order to manipulate its contents. For instance a `Uint8Array`:

```
buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
view.set([1,2,3,4]);
//or
buffer = Uint8Array.from([1,2,3,4]).buffer;
```

[TypedArray#set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set)

[TypedArray.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an `ArrayBuffer` with a particular type using something like `a = Uint8Array.from([1, 2, 3])`.